# How to debug 'Error in deparse_vector'?

Tags: r, leaflet, dplyr

I'm attempting to generate leaflet popup content and will *sometimes* get the following error:

```
Error in deparse_vector(x) : 
CHAR() can only be applied to a 'CHARSXP', not a 'character'
```

I'm not sure how to debug this. I also solicit strategies to avoid the problem.

Below is an attempt to provide a reproducible sample:

```
# this sometimes reproduces the error
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)

n <- 1000
set.seed(3)
df <- data.frame(id = stringi::stri_rand_strings(n, 25), 
                 b = as.character(sample(0:1, n, replace=T,prob=c(0.5,0.5))),
                 longitude = sample(-180:180, n, replace=T),
                 latitude = sample(-90:90, n, replace=T),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

makeUrl <- function(b, id) {
  as.character(
    if(b == '0'){
      htmltools::a(paste0("B ",id), href=paste0("https://www.b0.com/",id))
    } else {
      htmltools::a(paste0("B ",id), href=paste0("https://www.b1.com/",id))
    }
  )
}

# I think this introduces the 'error'
df2 <- df %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(theUrl = makeUrl(b, id))

# would love to know how to "execute" the tilde w/o leaflet
leaflet(df2) %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(popup = ~theUrl) %>%
  addTiles()
```

After the leaflet call, I will sometimes get the error mentioned.

If I do this df3 instead of creating df2 (which is ugly)

```
makeContent <- function(x,df) {
  b <- df[x,]$b
  id <- df[x,]$id
  makeUrl(b, id)
}

df3 <- df
df3$theUrl <- sapply(seq(1, nrow(df3)), makeContent,df3)


leaflet(df3) %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(popup = ~theUrl) %>%
  addTiles()
```

The error does not seem to manifest.

dplyr 0.5.0.9001

leaflet 1.1.0

R 3.4.0

Comment: Generic advice: `debugonce(deparse_vector)` before running your code will make you enter an interactive debugger when the error occurs again, allowing you to inspect things

Comment: Thanks. In this case, `deparse_vector` isn't available in the env, but I'll keep `debugonce` in mind for the future.

Comment: It's `debugonce(jsonlite:::deparse_vector)` (three colons since it's not exported indeed). I tried it but it seems to be of little help in your case anyway